# How can i use ajax data variable use under submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I click submit button, I cannot receive the value `yearend`. Instead I got an undefined value. How can I get `yearend` value when I click submit button?

My code:

```
$("#company").change(function() {

    $("#dFrom").val("");
    $("#dTo").val("");
    var pass_code = $("#company").val();
    var callpage = "dentrycomp.php?pass_code=" + pass_code
    var yearend= null;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: callpage,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            yearend= data,
            $("#content").html("")
            $("#content").html(data)
        }
    });
    //var yearend = "<?php echo $_SESSION['yearend'] ; ?>"
    alert(yearend +"company");
    this alert box getting the right value yearend.i want that value recieve in under submit button                         
    return true;
});


$('#submit').live('click',function() {
//var yearend = "<?php echo $_SESSION['yearend'] ; ?>"
alert("this is submit button"+yearend);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Are you executing it where the commented out statements are or is this the exact code executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var yearend = null;

$("#company").change(function() {

    $("#dFrom").val("");
    $("#dTo").val("");
    var pass_code = $("#company").val();
    var callpage = "dentrycomp.php?pass_code=" + pass_code

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: callpage,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            yearend = data,
            $("#content").html("")
            $("#content").html(data)
        }
    });

    //var yearend = "<?php echo $_SESSION['yearend'] ; ?>"
    alert(yearend + "company");
    this alert box getting the right value yearend.i want that value recieve in under submit button
    return true;
});

$('#submit').live('click', function() {
//var yearend = "<?php echo $_SESSION['yearend'] ; ?>"
alert("this is submit button" + yearend); });
```

You should declare `yearend` globally i.e. at the top of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of var scope. You must define variable before the request and then redefine it and get it after the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior with ajax outside your ajax call `yearned` is `undefined`. Put your on click function in ajax call itself. So, once your ajax call is finished and successful you'll attach your event listener in the success function. Use this logic instead:

```
$.ajax({
                              type: "GET",
                              url: callpage,
                              async: false,
                              success: function(data) {
                              yearend= data,
                              $("#content").html("")
                              $("#content").html(data)
                              $('#submit').live('click',function(){
                              //var yearend = "<?php echo $_SESSION['yearend'] ; ?>"

                               alert("this is submit button"+yearend);
                               });

                              }


                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
                              type: "GET",
                              url: callpage,
                              async: false,
                              success: function(data) {
                              yearend= data,
                              $("#content").html("")
                              $("#content").html(data)
                              $('#submit').live('click',function(){

                               alert("this is submit button"+yearend);
                               });

                              }

                            });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI ,.live() method is deprecated